# Where should the git directory be in a IntelliJ IDEA file hierarchy?

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

I am learning java and using JetBrains' IntelliJ IDEA as IDE. I am working on a small project which I would like to track via git/GitHub, as I am also learning how to use it.

**My question is: where should I place the git directory (i.e. where should the .git folder go)?**

As you might be aware, IntelliJ automatically creates the following folder structure when you create a project:

- `.idea` folder created by IntelliJ
- `out` folder containing compiled classes
- `src` folder containing the source code (.java files)
- `projectName.iml` file created by IntelliJ

I am hesitating between putting it in the root folder of the project or in the `src` folder. My gut feeling would push for the latter, as this is what I'm mostly interested in sharing, but I would like to know what the best practice is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, You should really keep it in the root folder and simply create `.gitignore` with all the folders that you are not interested in putting to Your repo.

This is because You really want your root folder to be the git repository, because of practical reasons. If You would keep it in the `src` folder then you would basically leave out everything that is in the root folder, like for example `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` or other files. What is more You would make it harder for other people to use such project, due to the fact that most of the IDEs actually uses the format with `src/main` and `src/test` folders.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to put root directory to git and list everything you don't want to push to git in .gitignore file. You can use ay open source java project as example, i.e. https://github.com/apache/jmeter
You can see the .gitignore content: https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/trunk/.gitignore